# Can you input binary to python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a 8bit Binari-Decimal translator but I've got stuck.

I haven't found anything online about it but I think its either that *"input()"* isn't the function I should be using or that I missed some *""* or *()* from the latest version.

```
nb = input ("0.-Num a binario /n1.-Binario a num:  ") //choose:1.DecimaltoBinary2.BinarytoDecimal
if nb == 0 :
    nb = input ("NaB:  ")   //input number to translate
    if nb>127 :    
        print "1"           //if bigger than 127 is 1xxxXXXX
        nb = nb-128         //remove 128 (or 1000 0000 in binary) 
    else :
        print "0"           //else 0xxxXXXX
    if nb>63 :
        print "1"
        nb = nb-64
    else :
        print "0"
    if nb>31 :
        print "1"
        nb = nb-32
    else :
        print "0"
    if nb>15 :
        print "1"
        nb = nb-16
    else :
        print "0"
    if nb>7 :
        print "1"
        nb = nb-8
    else :
        print "0"
    if nb>3 :
        print "1"
        nb = nb-4
    else :
        print "0"
    if nb>1 :
        print "1"
        nb = nb-2
    else :
        print "0"
    if nb>0 :
        print "1"
        nb = nb-1
    else :
        print "0"
    if nb>0 :
        print "ERROR"          //if nb==0 its OK, if nb>0 jumped some step
if nb==1 :
    nb = input("BaN: ")
    a = 0                      //set output variable to 0
    if nb>9999999 :            //check if the first bit is 1 (if nb is 1000 0000 or higher)
        a = a + 128            //add the bits value to output variable
        nb = nb - 10000000     //remove the first bit  1xxxXXXX - 1000 0000 == 0xxxXXXX
    if nb>999999 :
        a = a + 64
        nb = nb - 1000000
    if nb>99999 :
        a = a + 32
        nb = nb - 100000
    if nb>9999 :
        a = a + 16
        nb = nb - 10000
    if nb>999 :
        a = a + 8
        nb = nb - 1000
    if nb>99 :
        a = a + 4
        nb = nb - 100
    if nb>9 :
        a = a + 2
        nb = nb - 10
    if nb>0 :
        a = a + 1
        nb = nb - 1
    if nb>0 :             //check if every bit has been read
        print "ERROR"
    print "%d" % (a,)     //print the output value
```

The error comes when I input a binary that does not start with 1. When inputing between 0111**1111**-0100**0000** it gives *ERROR 63*,
when 0011**1111**-0010**0000** gives *ERROR 31*, etc.

It looks like if it jumped the first **1** it finds (unless the one valued 128). Can anyone test it and tell me what you get, please?

If you know what's wrong please tell me, even if there's a library shortcut I'd like to know what where and why it's wrong. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You tagged this `Python 3` but are using code which only makes sense in Python 2. Which is it?

Comment: If you are using `Python 2`, which you seem to be using despite the tag you chose, you would need to use `raw_input()` to read  something like `011110` *as a string* -- and then you would need to convert the characters `'0'` and `'1'` to the *ints* `0` and `1`. The code itself is a bit of a mess. Are you familiar with loops?

Comment: In Python 2 your current code should work (not tested!) if you type in binary literals as 0b11111111 - with the 0b prefix.